# Add leading zeros after"0x" to make all numbers in a list to be of same length ( 8-digits)

Tags: regex

I have a long list of data pair that look like this:

```
{0x1023350, 0x3014},
{0x1023954, 0x3007},
{0x1023960, 0x10F},
{0x102396C, 0x2FF},
{0x10219, 0x16},
```

The numbers here can be anywhere from 2 digits to 8 digits, but my requirement is to pad them with leading zeros so that in the final output all the numbers are 8-digits long.

```
{0x01023350, 0x00003014},
{0x01023954, 0x00003007},
{0x01023960, 0x0000010F},
{0x0102396C, 0x000002FF},
{0x00010219, 0x00000016},
```

How can I do it using regular expressions (I am using notepad++ , but I am open to some other tool, if I cant do it in notepad++)

I am not as fluent in regex to try out any solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in two steps:

##### Step 1 - Add excess left padding

Search: `0x`
Replace: `0x00000000`

##### Step 2 - Match excess exactly and delete it

Search: `0x\d+(?=[\dA-F]{8}[,}])`
Replace: `0x`

---

The regex:

- `\d+` means one or more digits
- `(?=[\dA-F]{8}[,}])` means followed by 8 hex chars then a comma or `}`

---

Some python code to demonstrate:

```py
import re

str = """{0x1023350, 0x3014},
{0x1023954, 0x3007},
{0x1023960, 0x10F},
{0x102396C, 0x2FF},
{0x10219, 0x16},
"""
str = str.replace("0x", "0x00000000")
str = re.sub("0x\d+(?=[\dA-F]{8}[,}])", "0x", str)
print(str)
```

Output:

```
{0x01023350, 0x00003014},
{0x01023954, 0x00003007},
{0x01023960, 0x0000010F},
{0x0102396C, 0x000002FF},
{0x00010219, 0x00000016},
```

Comment: Hi, thank you , but it didnt produce the desired output. I will play around with it.

Comment: hex is not only a digit, so probably that's why it didn't work, I'd change it to 0x0+(?=[\w]{8}\W)

Comment: @Photonslave see edits

Comment: @Maku thanks, I didn't notice the hex chars. I've corrected my answer.